# Ruby pretty print strings

Tags: ruby, logging, printing

I have a map where key (a string) can have a very variable number of characters and I'd like to print it intelligently:

```
MAP = {
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2",
}
```

would print:

```
key1 -> value1
key2 -> value2
```

and

```
MAP = {
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2",
    "key3_dam_it_you_are_a_big_one_indeed" => "value3",
}
```

would print:

```
key1                                 -> value1
key2                                 -> value2
key3_dam_it_you_are_a_big_one_indeed -> value3
```

he idea is that key1 and key2 would change their print-line according to the size of key3.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not do it as you want?

Comment: Because I try to no re-implement the wheel every time I want a car. This is usually the type of thing languages have built in.

Comment: So why not use that built-in function?

Comment: that was the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
class Hash
  def nice_print
    max_key_length = keys.map(&:length).max
    each { |key, value| puts "#{key.ljust(max_key_length)} -> #{value}" }
  end
end
```

and you call

```
MAP.nice_print
```